# Mock method return based on object parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
public string methodName(ClassType object)
{
    If(object.value == 1)
        return "Yes";
    else If(object.value == 2)
        return "No";
    else
        return "whatever";
}
```

I am then calling this method in a unit test, and need to mock the return type based on the object value:

```
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(new methodName { value = 1}).Returns("Yes");
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(new methodName { value = 2}).Returns("No");
```

I know what I have written is wrong - but how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see the need to use a mocking framework here. Can you explain what you need to mock and maybe why?

Comment: @nvoigt, I'm speculating based on my own experience, but I assume the poster is testing some different bit of code that depends on an interface with a method called `methodName()`. The first example demonstrates sample return data from the production implementation of that interface. He is mocking that dependency rather than using the real one at test time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´m not that familiar with Moq, however I asume the following should do it. You should provide a single `Returns` for every possible value for your parameter:

```
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(It.Is<ClassType>(y => y.value == 1))).Returns("Yes");
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(It.Is<ClassType>(y => y.value == 2))).Returns("No");
```

This way whenever your `methodName`-method is called with `object.value == 1`, `"Yes"` is returned, while `object.value == 2` resolves to the method returning `"No"`.

However to me this makes not much sense as you´re mocking the behaviour of `methodName` with the exact same behaviour. I suppose this is just for research.

Comment: this is a simplified version of what I am doing - to illustrate the question I am asking. My actual code is different to this

Comment: Also, when mocking - this method would never get called so I would need to simulate its behaviour like this - vasically saying when this method gets called use this logic

Comment: @Alex That´s the purpose of mocking. However be aware that the method needs to be virtual in the base-class or that method is defined on an interface

Comment: @Alex And is `_Service` also declaraed as of the interface-type or as a concrete class-type?

Comment: It is an interface type

Comment: Then I suppose my solution should work, shouldn´t it?

Comment: So what are we talking about here? I guess it´s all right.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track. With Moq, you need to specify exactly which setup should match each input. You do it like this:

```
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(It.IsAny<ClassType>())).Returns("whatever");
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(It.Is<ClassType>(o => o.value == 1))).Returns("Yes");
_Service.Setup(x => x.methodName(It.Is<ClassType>(o => o.value == 2))).Returns("No");
```

The first line there sets up the mock to return "whatever" whenever this method is called with any value. The following two lines override that behavior for specific values.

I'd check out Moq's [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) guide for more details, and the [Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) section in particular.

Comment: my method does not take int as a parameter - it an takes an object

Comment: You're right - I've updated it. You want to specify your setup with a lambda to evaluate the expression handed in.

Comment: worth mentioning that methodName must be virtual

Comment: @Artem why is that - currently it is not virtual for me, but all my code is running fine and working?

Comment: @Artem, Moq works against interfaces. In this case, `_Service` must be defined as some interface, so the `virtual` keyword doesn't come into it.

Comment: @MattDillard yes, good catch. I assumed it was declared as a class