# Get an object from a service to allow test to run using xUnit and Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

This is probably due to my lack of understanding as I'm new to xUnit and Moq but I'm trying to test a post method in my controller, however in the controller, I have this line of code:

`var user = await _mapModelService.MapModelForNewUser(viewModel);`

This will pass the ViewModel to the service where it maps the ViewModel properties to a new Model ready for it to be written to the database later.

In the test, I'm trying to use Moq to use the service and return a new Model. This code I have is like so:

```
mapModelService.Setup(x => x.MapModelForNewUser(new NewUserVm())).ReturnsAsync(new User()
{
    UserId = 1
});
```

All I need is the id so I can test the route values once it's finished, however the user object in the controller is null and the test fails with a NullReferenceException. I'm not trying to test the object the service returns, it's just so the test runs.

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: The suggested answer does not answer my question, it appears to be very similar to what I'm already doing. I've tried creating new instances of ViewModel and Model and giving them arbitrary values and passing those instead, with the same result.

EDIT 2: The service is asynchronous, id that makes a difference how this is called but I was under the impression `ReturnsAsync()` handles this.

EDIT 3: Here's the full test.

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task NewUser_ShouldRedirectToNewCreatedUserWhenModelStateIsValid_WithUserDetailsVm()
        {
            // Arrange
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger<UserController>>();
            var vmService = new Mock<IViewModelService>();
            var userRepo = new Mock<IUserRepo>();
            var mapModelService = new Mock<IMapModelService>();

            var userController = new UserController(logger.Object, vmService.Object, userRepo.Object, mapModelService.Object);
            var redirectToRouteResult = await userController.NewUser(It.IsAny<NewUserVm>()) as RedirectToRouteResult;
            

            // Act
            mapModelService.Setup(x => x.MapModelForNewUser(It.IsAny<NewUserVm>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new User()
                {
                    UserId = 1
                });

            userController.ModelState.Clear();

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(redirectToRouteResult);
            Assert.False(redirectToRouteResult.Permanent);
            Assert.Equal("UserDetails", redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["Action"]);
            Assert.Equal("User", redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["Controller"]);
            Assert.Equal(1, redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["id"]);
            Assert.Equal("note", redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["requiredTab"]);
        }
```

Comment: For `x.MapModelForNewUser(new NewUserVm())` instead of passing a new instance of `NewUserVm`, why don't you pass it the actual instance of `NewUserVm`, seems to me like the mock setup for `MapModelForNewUser` will never happen unless you give it the actual user (aka: `viewModel` )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock method return based on object parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518396/mock-method-return-based-on-object-parameter)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried passing it arbitrary values but it still comes back as null. When you use Moq, is it supposed to use the service? When I set breakpoints, it seems to skip over it.

Comment: @mattfullerdev The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: If you do not care about the viewmodel being passed in then use `It.IsAny<NewUserVm>()` in the setup

Comment: The setup needs to be before invoking the subject under test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about the viewmodel being passed in then use `It.IsAny<NewUserVm>()` in the setup.

Also the `Setup` needs to be done before invoking the subject under test

```
// Arrange

// ...omitted for brevity

mapModelService
    .Setup(x => x.MapModelForNewUser(It.IsAny<NewUserVm>())) //<--NOTE THE ARGUMENT MATCHER
    .ReturnsAsync(new User() {
        UserId = 1
    });

var viewModel = new NewUserVm();

// Act
var redirectToRouteResult = await userController.NewUser(viewModel) as RedirectToRouteResult;
       
// Assert

// ...
```

The original setup was done with a specific instance that will never be used when exercising the test. Thus the mock will never behave as you would expect.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for a better understanding of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi I had actually tried that but that also didn't work. I've updated with my full test in case something else is interferring. In the mean time, I'll take a look at the docs you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. Appreciate it.